# How to spin up the fan on hp presario cq without disabling the keyboard and mousepad?

Tags: fan, speedfan

This is the model of the laptop - cq56-120sq

Currently the only way for me to max out the fan to 100% is partially running the [bios](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp52501-53000/sp52622.exe) update obtainable from the hp support page - unfortunately this method breaks my keyboard and mousepad.

Is there some painless way of doing this?

I've tried countless of speed fan controlling programs but none of them were working or supporting that exact model.

Answer (score 0):

What's the order you install drivers after the BIOS flash?

1. BIOS Update the BIOS firmware.
2. HP System Utilities
3. Chipset driver
4. PCMCIA and/or Smartcard drivers  Security
5. Intel Matrix Storage Manager Serial ATA
6. Audio driver Audio
7. Video driver Video
8. Network interface card or Ethernet drivers
9. ControlPoint System Manager, ControlPoint Security Manager, and ControlPoint Connection Manager
10. HP Power Management
11. Wireless network drivers
12. Bluetooth drivers
13. Mouse, keyboard, touchpad and input device drivers
14. Intel vPro or AMT (if available)
15. Wireless mobile broadband card drivers (if available)
16. Modem drivers (if available)
17. Touch screen driver (if available)